# Javascript + Quicksort: how does this wikipedia implementation work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to up my javascript + algorithm game. I'm looking at this quicksort implementation on wikipedia: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort#JavaScript

```
function qsort(a) {
  if (a.length == 0) return [];

  var left = [], right = [], pivot = a[0];

  for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] < pivot ? left.push(a[i]) : right.push(a[i]);
  }

  return qsort(left).concat(pivot, qsort(right));
}
```

I understand the concept. It's breaking up the original array into smaller parts recursively and sorting the smaller arrays. However, I don't see how this `qsort` function works when it never returns the left / right arrays (something like `return leftArrayResult;`). Doesn't that mean qsort always returns `null` or an empty array? So `qsort(left).concat(pivot, qsort(right)` would always be `null.concat(pivot, null)` and therefore never work?

Comment: Why not just give it a sample array and log the values to see how it works?

Comment: It never returns `null`; it returns an array, which may or may not be empty.

Comment: When it reaches length of 0, it will return the empty array. From there all open stacks will be closed. As you see left and right are passed in. Simply draw the stacks yourself with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have the unsorted `[6,10,4,1]`,

First phase:

`qsort[6,10,4,1];`

`pivot = 6;`

In the for loop with each pass of the loop numbered:

1. `10 > 6`, added to right array
2. `4 < 6`, added to left array
3. `1 < 6`,  added to left array

`left = [4,1]; right = [10]; pivot = 6;`

qsort is then called recursively on the left array again which is `[4,1]`.

Second phase:

`pivot = 4`

In the for loop with each pass of the loop numbered:

1. `1 < 4`, added to left array

`left = [1]; right = []; pivot = 4;`

qsort is then called recursively and on the left array again which is `[1]`.

Third phase:

`pivot = 1`

the for loop is not executed.

`left = []; right = []; pivot = 1;`

qsort is called on the left array.

Fourth phase:

This time qsort returns an empty array.

Execution now moves to the concat call in the third stack taking the empty array and concatenates it to 1 and the result of `qsort(right)` which will also return an empty array. So the returned value now is `[1]`.

Execution now moves back to the second phase where `[1]` is concatenated to the pivot of 4 and the result of `qsort([])` so we now have a return value of `[1,4]`.

Execution now returns to the first phase so we concatenate the result of `[1,4]` to the pivot of 6 and the result of `qsort([10])` to get our result of `[1,4,6,10]`.

I hope this is easy enough to understand!

Comment: great thanks for the explanation and actually answering the question